# R: using character vector subset within 'require' function not working

Tags: r, function, package

In order for my function work correctly, I first need to load some packages. I want to load this packages automatically. That is, in the very first part of the code, it will look up whether the required package is loaded, than load it if it is not already loaded. I came up with the code below

```
  #Install and/or load necessary packages
  packages <- c("chron","ncdf","rgdal")
  i.count <- 1
  while (i.count <= length(packages)) {
    if (packages[i.count] %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE) {
      install.packages(packages[i.count])
      require(packages[i.count])
    } else if (packages[i.count] %in% (.packages()) == FALSE) {
      require(packages[i.count])
    }
    i.count = i.count + 1
  }
```

Given the above code, I am getting the following err when running the line `require(packages[i.count])`

Err:

```
    c("Loading required package: [", "Loading required package: packages", "Loading required package: i.count")
Failed with error:  ‘'package' must be of length 1’
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!loaded) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
require(packages[i.count],character.only=TRUE)
```